# Are EBS Snapshots isolated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created AMI of one of my instances, but during the process the instance rebooted and it required lot of work to make it functional again. I was creating AMI because I didn't wanted to touch the original volume and instance.

Now after the process, I deleted the AMI but the Snapshot of Volumes is present there in EBS section of AWS Console. If I create a new volume from the snapshots (one is 200 GB, another 8 GB for instance), will it affect the original volume or instance in any way? I don't want to corrupt the data of original instance in any way because it won't be recovered if corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Using a stored Amazon EBS snapshot to create a new Volume does not change the Snapshot in any way.

Think of the Snapshot as a backup disk. When creating a new Volume, it simply *copies* the contents to the new Volume. The Snapshot is unaffected.

When AWS receives a request to create a Snapshot of an Amazon EBS Volume, the Snapshot will contain a copy of the disk at that immediate point in time. Changing the contents of the EBS Volume after that time will not impact the Snapshot. Similarly, use of the Snapshot will not impact the existing EBS Volume attached to the Amazon EC2 instance.

All data flows from `EC2 Instance --> Snapshot --> New EBS Volume` (and never back the other way).

So, yes, they are "isolated" although that is not a term that is generally used.